# How to switch between textviews with horizontal scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Okay, I don't think I'm using the right terms on Google Search because I've tried over 40 times and haven't gotten any results.

My question : Analogous to the android's multiple screens, can I have multiple textviews in my app? And a textview indicator(which indicates which textview is currently being viewed like the android screen indicator indicates the current screen being displayed). If this is possible can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: have you looked into using fragments? what API version is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

This is what I wanted. Thanks for the help anyway Code Droid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to understand.  A TextView is a View.  A View must be displayed within a ViewGroup, such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.  So you always have an encasing View. The question is how do you know which text view is currently being viewed. If its the only text view visibile in the ViewGroup than you know its the one being viewed.  But if there are multiple text views than of course there no selection of the TextView.  So unless you have retina tracking or something like that there is no way to know.